# why does this sql don't use key?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

```
mysql> explain select * from dg_users order by uid desc limit 83,10;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dg_users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2319 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from dg_users order by uid desc limit 82,10;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dg_users | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   92 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This like the result.
when I change the "limit 82,10" to "limit 83,10", the key will lost.

I just want to know why ? ThinkS

Comment: Sounds like there's some buffer that's not large enough for MySQL to be able to offset by that one additional record using only the index... what version of MySQL; and what storage engine does `dg_users` use?

Comment: mysql's version: 5.6.12 and the engine is myisam.